# Не работает page adapter

Tags: activity, android, swipe, java, sliding

По [этой инструкции](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131889/) делаю слайдинг. Вышло следующие:

fltut.xml

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/fld1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/at1" />
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="1/12" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

fltut.java

```
package dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class fltut extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fltut);

    }

}
```

flslider.java

```
package dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class flslider extends fltut {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ) {
             View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fltut, null);
             TextView textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.desc);
             textView.setText("@string/fld" + i);
             ImageView imgView = (ImageView) page.findViewById(R.id.img);
             int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("R.drawable.fl"+i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
             imgView.setImageResource(drawableResourceId);
             TextView stpView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.stp);
             stpView.setText(i + "/12");
             pages.add(page);

        }

        SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(pages);
        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

        setContentView(viewPager);

    }
}
```

SamplePagerAdapter.java

```
package dlp.app.content.paperplanes.free;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    List<View> pages = null;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(List<View> pages){
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
        View v = pages.get(position);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState(){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0){
    }
}
```

**При запуске на телефоне отображается 1 page и всё. На касания не реагирует. *В чём проблема/как исправить?***

p.s. **Тому, кто даст хороший рабочий ответ, дам 50 баллов.**

p.p.s. Если в flslider.java viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); поменять на viewPager.setCurrentItem(2); всё-равно покажется первая страница

p.p.p.s. *Прошу свои извинения за много букв. Просто уже сижу несколько часов и нечего не могу придумать*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поломал немного голову над Вашим кодом. Все потому, что главная активити у Вас - `fltut`. Она и показывает один экран. Так как визуально он такой, как Вы ожидаете, Вы не можете понять, что это не `PageView` (Это легко проверить, если запустить новомодный monitor и перейти на вкладку Hierarchy View и просто посмотреть дерево).

Я просто перенес код `onCreate` из `flslider.java` в `fltut.java` в метод `onCreate` (заменив те две строки) и все заработало (я правда закомментировал немного кода, где прописываются картинки).